# Differential Calculus question: Finding the formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The line l:

- Intersects the line  $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2 +9} - x^2 + 5x$
- Is parallel to the line $m: y = 5x-2 $

Find the formula of line l algebraically.

So, I found the derivative of f, which is $ \dfrac{x} {\sqrt{x^2+9}} - 2x+5$, and I know that line l has a slope of 5. So I got to the point $ \dfrac{x} {\sqrt{x^2+9}} - 2x = 0 $, but I don't know how to solve this..

Comment: Subtract 5 from both sides.

Comment: Yes, but after that you still have something I can't solve.

Comment: Add $2x$ to both sides, and then square both sides.

Comment: To be honest, I think something is up with the question. The only line that is tangent to $m$ is $m$, so that's your answer. It would make a lot more sense if it was tangent to $f$ and intersected $m$ (which seems to be what the question was, given your work).

Comment: I made a mistake, parallel to, not tangent to, sorry!

Comment: There are many lines that intersect the graph of $f$ and are parallel to the line $m$. ($f$ is not a line.) The line $m$ itself intersects $f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+9}} - 2x = x(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+9}}-2)$. So either $x = 0$ or $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+9}}=2$ or $\frac{1}{x^2+9}=4$ or $4(x^2+9) = 1$. This one you should be able to solve.

Comment: Why $4(x^2+9)=1$? Where does that come from?